# Would I be "invisible" if I travel with the speed of light

Tags: speed-of-light

If I travel to some planet with the speed of light and come back would someone notice I wasn't there or it'd be that fast that no one would

Answer (score 1):

That depends on which planet you are going to travel.
Although light travels at a very high speed, it takes time for the light to get from point A to point B. In this case, even if you were to travel to the moon with the speed of light, it would take around 3 seconds to reach the moon and return to your initial location. 3 seconds is enough for everyone to notice that you aren't there. So that I hope answers your question. If even traveling to the moon at the speed of light and returning would take 3 seconds, imagine the time needed to travel to much distant planets. So you would only be "invisible" if you were to travel in Earth-comparable distances. Like from one country to another.

Answer (score 0):

If you travel at the speed of light you don't have past neither future. So for you exist only now because time is infintely contracted: this is quite unphysical situation for you.

Moreover each massive body can't reach speed of light, else it gains infinite energy due to gamma factor.
Even if you reach that speed (unphysical) you have to take account of Doppler, with infinite gamma factor in each direction (either for longitudinal or transverse Doppler) to multiply or divide photons frequency, so you emits in some direction zero energy photons (no photon) or infinite energy photons... maybe you have to accept that is impossible.